# Java regex to match first argument of a method call in Java code

Tags: java, regex

Given the following text

```
log.debug("find by example successful, result size: " + results.size(), exception);
```

How can I match the first argument of the method call, in this case the text between the first parenthesis and the last comma:

```
"find by example successful, result size: " + results.size()
```

I started with the following pattern:

```
Pattern.compile("log\\.([\\w]+)\\((.+?)\\)", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

but if I try to match up to the comma it won't work:

```
Pattern.compile("log\\.([\\w]+)\\((.+?),?\\)", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Comment: What if the above line of code is in a comment, would you still want to match it?

Comment: No problem if it is in a comment.

Comment: What is the acceptable level of error? Note that you should find a Java code parser if you want it to always work correctly. For example, https://github.com/matozoid/javaparser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the `,` in the regex and also you need to remove the `?` quantifier inside the second capturing group. So that the regex engine would match all the characters upto the last `,` greedily.

```
Pattern.compile("log\\.(\\w+)\\((.+),", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

And get the string you want from group index 2.

```
String s = "log.debug(\"find by example successful, result size: \" + results.size(), exception);";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("log\\.(\\w+)\\((.+),");
 Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(s);
 while(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
}
```

Output:

```
"find by example successful, result size: " + results.size()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\\(.*,
```

Try this.See demo    .This will give the match between first `(` and last `,`.

https://regex101.com/r/nL5yL3/10